# Paypal Pre-aapproved Payments with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal

**My Scenario**

Im trying to setup Laravel to redirect me to a page where i can sign the user up for pre approved payments. But I cant find a laravel package that allows me to do so, here are the 3 that ive tried so far!

1: https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal

2: https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal

3: https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment

They all only give me payment options but no option to set up pre-approved payments...

**My Question**

Is there a package or method for use with laravel that allows me to implement pre-approved payments?

Comment: So recurring payments then? https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Subscriptions/what-is-a-pre-approved-payment/td-p/1028739

Comment: Recurring payments isnt the same as pre-approved is it? Because i was lead to believe theyre different things, but are they  the same?

Comment: @ka_lin So on one of the packages it says to create a billing agreement, or a subscription, is there a difference between the two?

Comment: I cannot say...sorry

Answer (score 0):

Our [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) isn't a Laravel specific package, but it's compatible with Composer and works great inside Laravel.  It includes all of the calls you would need to setup billing agreements, preapproved payments, and pretty much everything PayPal offers.  It makes those calls very quick and easy for you, too.

Comment: Hey can i just ask, is there a way to implement the fraud detection software in the UK? because i cant sign up for it, it would be a great help but ive read we dont have access to this feature just yet!

Comment: Which fraud features are you wanting?

Comment: Paypal Pro/ PayFlow fraud protection, i try to sign up but i think because im in the UK we dont have access to it yet? I basically need to know if its paypal or my other service that's detecting fraudulent activity, its becoming stressful :/